# NoReverseMatch at ListView with Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Ii got an error after add form to my `ListView` class.

here my `models.py`

```
class Holiday(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("app:holiday_list"
```

here my `views.py`

```
class HolidayListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'holidays'
    model = models.Holiday

class HolidayCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'date_from', 'date_to')
    model = models.Holiday
```

and here my `holiday_list.html`

```
....

<form method="post" action="{% url 'holiday-create' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_name">
      <input type="text" name="date_from" required="" id="id_date_from">
      <input type="text" name="date_to" required="" id="id_date_to">

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">

</form>
....
some code to list all data
```

and my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^/$',views.HolidayListView.as_view(), name='holiday_list'),
url(r'^create/$',views.HolidayCreateView.as_view(),name='holiday-create'),
```

i got an error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /app/holiday/
Reverse for 'holiday-create' not found. 'holiday-create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

did I miss something.

Comment: In your urls.py (in project) did you have `namespace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your `Holiday` model, you're using a namespace of `app`. The URL in your template should specify that.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'app:holiday-create' %}">
```